# Help with ASP.net Code

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<h3>Request ID:<%=Request["request_id"]%></h3>
</asp:Content>
```

The Code above is not working. How do I display the request id without touching the code behind file?

Comment: Are you sure there is a value for request_id in the GET/FORM collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
http://YOUR_SERVER/your_aspx_file.aspx?request_id=2134234
```

Comment: sorry it was my mistake. i missed the paranthesis for response.write`. it works now

Answer (score 0):

Please check your html source code if the `<h3>` tag is inside. Because if it is not, the placeholder is hidden oder the inner controls has been removed before rendering.